# Setting up the crontab on amazon ec2 cloud (Linux server)

Tags: php, linux, cron

I need to run a php file on every 2 hours, so i am using this command

```
* */2 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sports/webservices/rss-insert.php
```

i am also using this

```
* */2 * * * php /var/www/html/sports/webservices/rss-insert.php
```

But both are not working. can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crontab you have made will run every minute of every second hour rather than every two hours.

In order to get it to run every two hours you need something like this:

```
5 */2 * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/sports/webservices/rss-insert.php
```

which will run it 5 minutes after every second hour e.g 2:05, 4:05...

This is assuming your script is able to run. Try running the command portion from the cron by hand at the command line and make sure it does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me definitely work for you.

`0 0-23/2 * * * php /var/www/html/sports/webservices/rss-insert.php`